# PHP fetch Youtube Comments without API

Tags: php, curl, youtube, automation, token

I am using PHP and am trying to scrape youtube comments but without using the youtube API

I can fetch the first page of comments just fine, but the "show more" form with token is being difficult.

here is the live headers for the show more request

```
https://www.youtube.com/comment_ajax?action_load_comments=1&filter=-kWHMH2kxXs&order_by_time=false

POST /comment_ajax?action_load_comments=1&filter=-kWHMH2kxXs&order_by_time=false HTTP/1.1
Host: www.youtube.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
X-YouTube-Page-CL: 78947767
X-YouTube-Page-Timestamp: Fri Oct 31 12:43:20 2014 (1414784600)
X-YouTube-Variants-Checksum: 9225d6367a37f5c51f11f11009c7ed18
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=-kWHMH2kxXs
Content-Length: 1712
Cookie: VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=xJf1SvXMyvQ; PREF=fv=12.0.0&al=en&f5=30&f1=50000000; YSC=AQRpt5kYK6k; ACTIVITY=1414984537233; SID=DQAAANgAAAAVDrV25qIMIY1h4EnHCkB8QuHQpVPP2YhTT2PPvE2wkYbGLdHG9xQWEX_ADKYlKolQJRwza-Js_dmVlB-No68zaXnhLFm0NnbUaEV4zsaUwT5R_Kg1YvR2RvixP0OIw603Gax8sXIfXHmALqdYxWJ46Dt1qh2TmVoX06w7KlOQgvBE6_yViqu4j0b1iUSdVwJfMkhi8NVymGGsHWOVm027hdYdKKJTUC8-PJYbVKvItugatr0dJRL5_s6_l-P1ZFP2-OKrhb0H3ORmPU1EaFtsbPB3ZFjut09hxPFKCOq51w; HSID=A7izZQDyAow9noXRe; SSID=ALKL6xYLDPNuetixT; APISID=mOy8lSC4EJ0mUUs_/AjHuF16GPSuuL0gzQ; SAPISID=tmpcNtK_8ScRg3Mc/AMrBhFSc1O6ejr4HK; LOGIN_INFO=fe8cf1ebd49b7874eaf88ae7e3930925c2sAAAB7IjgiOiAxMzY1NjQ3NTc1MzUsICI0IjogIkdBSUEiLCAiNyI6IDE0MTQ5NDk2NDcsICIxIjogMSwgIjIiOiAiSWtxR3c2a2ZQdVRRQktZWHhGdWRaZz09IiwgIjMiOiAyNzc5ODQzNTk2fQ==; lwb=1; wide=1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
page_token=Cg0Q8o2Ks8HdwQIgACgBErMHCAIQ6OuMlsHdwQIqpQe2m7DWq%2BSSlskBkZa45rrvrcmUAfyw%2B4WRtdrj%2FAG57%2FHkzJuNvcYB2POv74G5pZ8Mo%2Frf4Om0q%2FgS39TjhqfnzrMd6JbK9qnmj5sCueOj2YLYwozGAe7z0di9pPucHO3%2Fs42y3ejI%2BQHLhcen4eTv5x7NgNyI35nQrIcB1emWlMOJtcnlAdflt%2BbyjLnC4QGZktCSyZro5Anvhui%2BqObE%2B9kB5cahueaIkf27Ae7kkt%2Fry%2BqyOKfNh%2BCooZ%2FwcJWwt%2BP2xZmjGpO5lIqhrayYlQG4t9z%2Bo%2FDA2sEB94DOtZmc2dQG%2FavmlfWh5PkehJ6lrrLIzIW6Adr9%2BuHWkLmPFITArbbFleOkzQH8ytjyg7iuloABg6j8t%2Bj2ypG6AaeNhpf5yq6FnAGxq7u%2Bx6Sjl4EBg4vMmNDj3ulAsK7JrsSUz9%2FKAeTs4OfIwt33ygG277%2BRvaHOpE7Vqtuw6ZOy%2FR%2By7Nrixrj%2BzgWqs8avyoSK2tgBp6fHg%2BKLh4dr6NOqqLnb8JnnAYKH87SF%2B%2BXujgHDv7SArt7Z0ZUBu6Sy3YTBo%2FZ9%2Ft7QwYSLneytAaXG%2BfKblNOsVO3Bj%2BHxiqnLSJmuyeXj6ZT67wGK%2F%2FO9n9nA0uIBuIaez6%2BP1aWWAeybq8L%2F44efFuWNrO7h8JCCBPiVz8eq0sCnQcHjjaS2go3M5QH0wI3WwNa%2B9Uq1o8mZ85SZ4jiKs5O38prnsq8B5pDPvK%2FxlbFGz7%2FA%2BuSR2cffAZePkYuJ35n6Mt%2FUyO73kfqiOMGetu%2F%2Fr%2BCDkAHgkeLxh5K1ugWmoLjQis%2FZlBzfhbLI%2Ff7%2BjpkBrYHs0fvW%2B%2FvAAYCl99yYrb66hwGP6vuCparSjqYB1LbP14TY8ZJg7oyBnOGppMCgAY6u1rXq9pr9nAGn167P5Mmp1iCR%2F%2FLzxI%2Fw1njc5KjE2cGZpGSKivTwzv7HgmnkmIjsn7ra6vkB%2FI2mxMXS9ZPaAarLnYXDnumlggHvobaC%2BYuQr9kBk7i9hsKjgd1XiY7T2u%2BHys3PAb2Nw97A7Z2vrQGfof2Coeay7nSG68mDmpjcnQqWw7W157Tw9GLdq9TXpajvrbcByp2Iy8Cex6rdAfqvsIGn0uHwaMOap9bYho%2BaVLrAxbKru6C1ngGt1drm%2FsWs9yW%2Fm9722KfXxr4Bq8GDlZbnz4wPj4GPj5bd0MzOAb3ZiovalKGiL7zYhbO81fvlPJjlto%2Bh26qewgHUy%2B3ZxuXk4AYYAQ%3D%3D&session_token=QUFFLUhqa0RnaTI1Z3dnTVdTaTZEbUM2Vkp4WWpnTlJPUXxBQ3Jtc0tuN2g1WTh0c2FIa2JMU0FER1oxWU5HTzNtMzMyLXRuUEYzeldzMU5VMnhmOXdUN0U2TnEzNW9KSjFXb0FoV1Y0QUxSTG9SWXVlSXk0am50RTFBcUhnSi10QklHdXVlcE5LUGVYLXZ0YzNvajUzYTZGRUhtbWVISklFS2JSSjVwRXdRWERua04yYktDd243NGFfOGcyVUdIZXVaMmc%3D
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.01
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 13424
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 03 Nov 2014 04:24:24 GMT
Expires: Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
Server: gwiseguy/2.0
x-content-type-options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Firefox-Spdy: 3.1
```

I am able to build my CURL request with all the URL parameters, that is the easy part

```
https://www.youtube.com/comment_ajax?action_load_comments=1&filter=-kWHMH2kxXs&order_by_time=false
```

However, how do I include the page_token?

I have the token extracted from the comments page show more form, but I don't know how I'm suppose to include it

I've tried this

```
$headers = array(
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "page_token=" . $dataToken
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

But I keep getting kicked back to an error

```
[HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Date: Mon, 03 Nov 2014 04:58:24 GMT Server: gwiseguy/2.0 Cache-Control: no-cache X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube Expires: Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST Content-Length: 0 Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.01 ]
```

I have all the needed data, I'm just not sure how I'm suppose to structure my CURL request.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The API is simpler, documented, gives you control about when Google will rate-limit you, and more reliable. Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although currently [only supported by the v2 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments), you should reconsider to [use it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments). After loading the first page of comments from

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-kWHMH2kxXs/comments?orderby=published

you would only have to follow the feed's `next` link to get the next batch of comments.

Comment: Interesting. I thought you needed to sign up with for an API key first and then the rate-limit would be applied to your data fetches on the comments. Do you know if this method is capped in any way? Or can I fetch to my hearts content?

Comment: When I first tried this method it seemed to work well, but now it doesn't seem to work for me. I fetch your link, prints off 25 results of 2520 total. I fetch the next link [ https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-kWHMH2kxXs/comments?orderby=published&amp;start-token=Cg0QnryJirztwwIgACgBEhQIABDYo5jMo%2B3DAhiImvTE3uDDAhgCIBk%3D&amp;max-results=25&amp;orderby=published ] but when I try to use the next link it just returns the same first results, even if I change the max results variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is capped, but I am pretty sure that your approach has an even more stringent limit, since it is not an official API at all. Your URL does not work because you forgot to properly XML-decode the URL before using it (eg `&amp;` should be `&` in the final URL)

Answer (score 0):

page_token is not part of the headers, it is a POST variable.
You have to put it in the body part of your request.

Using curl, i think you have to use the following:

```
$fs="page_token=".urlencode("<your_token_goes_here>");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fs);
```

Comment: rather `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fs);` assuming that the token is properly URL encoded

Comment: Thanks for the help. Have you tested this? I've tried it out and I'm still getting the same forbidden error.